# Merging Vertices in Undirected Graph

Tags: java, methods, graph, graph-theory, vertices

I'm trying to merge the vertices in an undirected graph after removing an edge from it, using Java. I'm representing said graph using arrays of bags containing integers, with variables for number of vertices and edges. For example a hexagon graph would be represented as:
6 vertices, 6 edges
0: 5 1
1: 2 0
2: 3 1
3: 4 2
4: 5 3
5: 0 4

The numbers before the colons are the vertices and the numbers after are the vertices they're connected to.

If I remove the edge connecting vertices 1 and 2 I obtain this:
6 vertices, 5 edges
0: 5 1
1: 0
2: 3
3: 4 2
4: 5 3
5: 0 4

I then want to merge those two vertices (1 and 2) to obtain:
5 vertices, 5 edges
0: 1 4
1: 0 2
2: 1 3
3: 2 4
4: 3 0

Here is my latest attempt at coding a solution (it's very incomplete, but at least it's something):

```
public Graph MergeVerticies(int start, int end)
{
    Graph tempGraph = new Graph(V - 1); //V = number of vertices

    for(int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < V; j++)
        {
            if(isEdge(i,j))
            {
                if(i == start && j == end)
                {
                    //not sure
                }
                else if(i == end && j == end)
                {
                    //not sure
                }
                else if(i >= end && j >= end)
                {
                    tempGraph.addEdge(i-1,j-1);
                }
                else if(i <= end && j >= end)
                {
                    tempGraph.addEdge(i,j-1);
                }
                //Seems like this would take a lot of conditions
                //There is probably a simpler set of conditions
            }
        }
    }
    return tempGraph;
}
```

Start and end are the vertices being merged. tempGraph is the new graph being created with the merged vertices.

Comment: What happens to these 2 edges from your initial graph: 4: (5 3) and
5: (0 4) in the third step?

Comment: When the whole structure of the Graph is represented not via *vertices*, but via *indices of vertices*, this is rather complicated: When a vertex is removed, you have to update the whole graph, because all the indices have to be updated. However, some information about the methods that are currently available in your `Graph` class might be helpful here.

Comment: The vertices are renumbered after the vertices are merged (merging removes a verticy). I should've mentioned that this renumbering is important and a big reason why solving this is difficult for me

Comment: You are correct Marco13, sorry about the terminology. I have an isEdge method which checks for the existence of an edge when given indicies of vertices, an addEdge method which checks for the existence of an edge using isEdge before adding, a removeEdge method, and a toString method for output. I can put the code for them in the post if it's helpful (didn't want to make it too long).